# 3D Building Generator Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, 3d-analyst, arcscene, openlayers-2

I am using ArcGIS desktop 10 and I would like to change a 2D polygon into 3D building.

Does anyone have any idea from where I can download the **3D building generator tool** for ArcGIS Desktop?

I read about this tool [here](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc03/p0305.pdf).

This tool gives various features and can build complex roof tops for building sites. With this tool I can develop a rounded roof in 3D ..etc

Moreover, any suggestions how I can import this 3D buildings in a web service using asp.net and C#?

Any help please?

Comment: I've done a little searching but can't find it. Did find someone else asking the question about a year ago though, no reply: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/38957-3D-Building-Generator-Toolbar - maybe someone else will have better luck

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of this tool, and cannot find much mention of it outside the whitepaper you linked to. I think it is a proprietary toolbar, which may or may not be available for commercial use.

This type of operation is often performed using FME, which has been improved in recent years to allow the creation of 3D buildings with different shapes, styles and tiled images to give the impression of a full 3D model.

Such processes in FME are outlined in a number of articles on FMEpedia:

- [Town of High Level in 3D](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Town-of-High-Level-in-3D)
- [3D Building Generator Workspace](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/3D-Building-Generator-Workspace)
- [City of Gavle in 3D](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/City-of-Gavle-in-3D)

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing, converting 2D polygons to 3D buildings. I did it in OL3-Cesium though, without any tool, by coding only.

I had the coordinates for the polygon, and the height attribute for the building present. (Used a default value in case height was not provided).
What I did was adding the 2D polygon as it is to the map. In addition to that, I created a **top polygon** at the provided height or the default value. So now we have 2 polygons, base and top, 2 set of coordinates (I stored each in array). Next and most important step was to generate and add polygons representing the seperate faces of the 3D polygon.

So in the nutshell :

- Generate base polygon
- Generate top polygon
- Generate side faces / walls.

In actual, I was just generating the **arrays of coordinates**. Later on, I created polygon features using ol.geom.Polygon with the generated arrays, and added them to map.
I'm not having the code with me otherwise I would've shared.